# Find partial derivatives of $f(x)=\|x\|^\alpha$

Tags: partial-derivative, vector-analysis

Find partial derivatives of $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
$$f(x)=\|x\|^\alpha$$
outside of $(0,0)$ when $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. What values does $\alpha$ have to take for the partial derivatives to also exist at $(0,0)$?

I only know that for the partial derivatives to exist at a point $a$, there has to be a limit
$$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f(a+te_k)-f(a)}{t}$$

but I don't know how to use it. I'm also not sure how to find partial derivatives without including all the points.

Comment: What is $\|\cdot\|$ ?

Answer (score 1):

In

$$f(x)=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right)^{\alpha/2},$$ consider $x_k$ as the variable and the other components as constants.

Then using the usual differentiation rules,

$$\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial{x_k}}=\frac\alpha2\,2x_k\,\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right)^{\alpha/2-1}=\alpha x_k(f(x))^{1-2/\alpha}.$$

(In the summation, only the term $x_k^2$ contributes.)

---

In particular,

- for $\alpha=-1$, $-x_kf^3(x)$,
- for $\alpha=1$, $\dfrac{x_k}{f(x)}$, and
- for $\alpha=2$, $2x_k$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\Vert x \Vert = \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \cdots + x_n^2} = (x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \cdots + x_n^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$, so $\Vert x \Vert^\alpha = (x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \cdots + x_n^2)^\frac{\alpha}{2}$. This is a nice differentiable function in all the $x_i$, except possibly at $0$.

Comment: It's only a nice differentiable function if $\alpha/2 \ge 1$. If $\alpha/2 < 1$, it is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: Right. I'll edit